# How to know a file name exist while saving files randomly

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to save files randomly in any directory as per
user wish but with a default custom file name. Same time I want 
to know whether the file name is exist in the new directory.
If it exist the file name should be saved with a incremental number string

eg: if I am trying save a file, "MyFile.txt" in any directory in my computer

let's say in D:\, C:\, or in some Desktop folder, despite of wherever it is, it should
be able to find out the particular file name(MyFile.txt) is exist there in that
selected folder if it exist, then it should be saved with incremented number string
like MyFile-1.txt MyFile-2.txt MyFile-3.txt etc.

my present code is working fine with this requirement only if the directory name is hardcoded!

currently I am writing on a folder named "TestFolder" this should be removed it should be assigned to
any user selected folder, no idea of how to do this!!

Somebody please help me soon

```
def File_Save_Random(self):


    searchFile = "MyFile"
    fileList = os.listdir("TestFolder")

    self.filecount=0
    for currFile in fileList:
        exactFile = re.findall(searchFile + "*", currFile)                      
        if exactFile!=[]:
            self.filecount+=1 


    if self.filecount==0:


             WrtiteWord="My Test data writing"               
             #filePathTowrite="TestFolder"
             fileNameToWrite="/MyFile"+".txt"                 
             fileWriteVar=filePathTowrite+fileNameToWrite



             file_name = tk_fsave(title="Save File",
                                     initialdir="/",initialfile="MyFile.txt",filetypes=[("txtFile","*.txt")])  


             print file_name
             file = open(fileWriteVar, "w") 
             file.write(WrtiteWord+"\n")
             file.close() 



    if self.filecount>0:


             WrtiteWord="My Test data writing"                
             #filePathTowrite="TestFolder"

             incrementedFilename="MyFile"+ str(self.filecount) + ".txt"   ## this is the incremented file name

             fileNameToWrite= incrementedFilename ## this is the incremented file name

             fileWriteVar=filePathTowrite+fileNameToWrite


             file_name = tk_fsave(title="Save File",
                                     initialdir="/",initialfile=fileNameToWrite,filetypes=[("txtFile","*.txt")])  



             print file_name
             file = open(file_name, "w") 
             file.write(WrtiteWord+"\n")
             file.close()
```

Comment: You should use `os.path.exists()` instead of `os.listdir()`.

Comment: @John, ok thanks, I should try.. but the confusion is on how to display the the new file incremented name before saving, always it showing "file is already exist do you want to replace" I mean I have to pass the new file name on file dialog priorly so I can avoid this dialog

Comment: So generate the basic/first filename, check if it exists, if it exists add a number, then increment that number until it doesn't exist.

Comment: @John, this my confusion for generating filename I have to write this code file_name = tk_fsave(title="Save File",....)
so it will display the dialog box and warn to replace the existing file replacement, if it is new name it won't ask!!
may be I am logically wrong, please correct me